# RODBC - sqlSave() does not write in an alias table in Oracle

Tags: r, oracle11g, rodbc

I am writing data into a table belonging to another schema using the function sqlSave() from the package RODBC. The user of the other schema has issued an alias with the same name as the original table. My user has enough rights to write into the table. The database is Oracle 11g.

This is how I write:

```
sqlSave(channel, object, tablename = table, safer=TRUE, rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE, verbose = FALSE, nastring = NULL, fast = TRUE)
```

When I run the sqlSave() I get an error message from  the Oracle DB. If i look at the SQL which R sends to the DB I see that R doubles the columns of the object I try to write. The SQL looks like so:

```
insert into table (column_A, column_B, column_A, column_B)
```

If the alias is removed and I use the schema as prefix to the table than I do not get any error message however R does not execute at all the query.

```
 sqlSave(channel, object, tablename = schema.table, safer=TRUE, rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE, verbose = FALSE, nastring = NULL, fast = TRUE)
```

Then I get:

```
insert into table (column_A, column_B) values(?,?)
```

The only thing it worked till now is to assign to the table a different alias as the table Name. In that case I manage to write in the table.

I would very much appreciate if anybody can suggest a solution to my Problem.
Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: what is the error message when trying to write to the alias?

Comment: Hi, I get an error msg from the Oracle database. Namely: "ORA-00947: not enough values"